# Struggling with understanding FOR and WHILE loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, computer-science

Description: Write a program that asks the user for a starting value and an ending value.  The program should then print all values inclusively between those values.   In addition, print out the sum and average of the numbers between those two values.

I need help trying to layout the program and getting it to run correctly. The program runs, the desired result just isn't the same. Can someone help me understand what i should do for it to work correctly. Thank you.

But, here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Prog152d
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader userin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String inputData;
        int starting, ending, sum;
        double avg;
        sum = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter Starting Value: ");
        inputData = userin.readLine();
        starting = Integer.parseInt( inputData );
        System.out.print("Enter Ending Value: ");
        inputData = userin.readLine();
        ending = Integer.parseInt( inputData );
        while ( starting <= ending)
        {

            System.out.println(starting);
            sum = sum + starting;
            avg = sum / 4;


           System.out.println("Sum of the numbers " + starting + " and " + ending + " is " + sum);
            System.out.println("The average of the numbers " + starting + " and " + ending     + " is " + avg);
        starting++;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Enter Starting Value:  5

Enter Ending Value :  8

5 

6 

7

8 

Sum of the numbers 5..8 is 26 

The average of the numbers 5..8 is 6.5
```

Comment: It would help if you'd specify what you get instead.

Why are you printing the sum inside the while loop? Just add to the sum inside the loop and print the result below it. Same with average. Also, why are you assuming in the average you are getting exactly 4 values?

Comment: @HunterLanders If my answer helped answer your question would you mind marking my answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is with the following line:

```
avg = sum / 4;
```

Don't use a constant value (in this case 4) unless it is the ONLY possibility. Instead use a variable and set its value equal to the difference between your starting and ending values:

```
int dif = ending - starting + 1; // add one because we want to include end ending value
avg = sum / dif;
```

Also, the average only needs to be calculated once at the end and therefore doesn't belong inside your loop. After making these adjustments you'll end up with something like this...

```
int start = starting; // we don't want to alter the value of 'starting' in our loop
while ( start <= ending)
{
    System.out.println(start);
    sum = sum + start;
    start++;
}

int dif = ending - starting + 1;
avg = (double)sum / dif;
System.out.println("Sum of the numbers between " + starting + " and " + ending + " is " + sum);
System.out.println("The average of the numbers between " + starting + " and " + ending + " is " + avg);
```